# How can I display `₹` properly in invoice pdf without changing core files

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

`₹` is properly displaying in front pages as well as product pages. But it is not displaying properly in pdf of invoice and shipment. How to change for proper displaying.

I have tried changing in `lib/zend/locale/data/root.xml` and also in `admin/system/manage currency/symbols` ,but no changes updating in pdf's.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1.Download the font that support Indian Rupee symbol. recommended dejavu-sans font.

2.place the font in lib directory.

3.open `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php` and `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php`

and replace

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Re-4.4.1.ttf');
```

with

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans.ttf');

(in _setFontRegular(), _setFontBold(), _setFontItalic() functions in both files.)
```

Comment: I don want to change in core files, to avoid conflict in other files

Comment: then the default font does not support Indian currency symbol.

Comment: Yes, but how to resolve it without core files

Comment: copy into local directory and change it there..

Comment: i have copied the directory Pdf from core and pasted in app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order............... and changed both abstarct.php. but no changes

Comment: Did you download the font too? And add into libraries

Comment: yes, and added correctly in path

Comment: Refresh ur cache and delete  var/cache folder

Comment: https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Editing+an+Invoice+PDF follow this link understanding the change font in pdf

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: did you change in these function too 

_setFontRegular(), _setFontBold(), _setFontItalic()

Comment: can you check your local.xml file inside app/etc what charset is there if not then try with adding charset

<charset>utf8</charset>

Comment: where to add the above line??

Comment: app/etc/local.xml

Comment: yes in local.xml,,,, above which line i have to add

Comment: after this <active>1</active> add your line

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for great solution, it is working fine for me to show the rupees symbol in invoice PDF in magento.

Solution Steps :

1.Download the font that support Indian Rupee symbol. recommended dejavu-sans font.

http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download

https://sourceforge.net/projects/dejavu/files/dejavu/2.36/dejavu-sans-ttf-2.36.zip/download

2.Place the font in lib directory(projectname/lib).

3.open app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php and `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php`

4. copy paste both files under local

a) `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`

b) `app/code/loacl/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php`

and replace

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Re-4.4.1.ttf');
```

with

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans.ttf');
```

(in `_setFontRegular()`, `_setFontBold()`, `_setFontItalic()` functions in both files.)

5. Admin -> System --> Manage Currency -->Symbols --> Copy your symbol like in my case "₹" and save.