# Hebrew words in PDF invoice are reversed and currency symbol not showing

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf, fonts, magento-2.1.3

I'm using **magento 2 CE 2.1.3**

When I'm trying to prin PDF invoice the hebrew words are reversed, for example:
`םולש` instead of `שלום`.
And also the currency symbol (NIS `₪`) is not showing.

[image]
I have seen this issue in several places:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911650/rupee-symbol-not-rendering-properly-on-invoice-pdf-in-magento

[How can I display `₹` properly in invoice pdf without changing core files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87934/how-can-i-display-%E2%82%B9-properly-in-invoice-pdf-without-changing-core-files)

but these solutions doesn't work on magento 2.
The closest thing I have found to change the font in the PDF is this:
[Adding new fonts to Pdf invoice Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117659/adding-new-fonts-to-pdf-invoice-magento-2/117668)

but I couldn't understand completely what I should place in the `AddFontToPdf.php` file...

I'll be glad for some help here..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For this answer: [Adding new fonts to Pdf invoice Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117659/adding-new-fonts-to-pdf-invoice-magento-2/117668), we can follow

*app/code/Vendor/PdfFont/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf">
        <plugin name="add_font_to_pdf" type="Vendor\PdfFont\Plugin\AddFontToPdf" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

*app/code/Vendor/PdfFont/Plugin/AddFontToPdf.php*

```
<?php

namespace RoyalCopenhagen\PdfFont\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class AddFontToPdf
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadInterface
     */
    protected $_rootDirectory;

    /**
     * AddFontToPdf constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    )
    {
        $this->_rootDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::ROOT);
    }

    public function beforeDrawLineBlocks($subject, $page, array $draw, array $pageSettings = [])
    {
        foreach ($draw as $key => $values) {
            if(isset($values['lines'])) {
                $lines = $values['lines'];
                foreach ($lines as $k => $v) {
                    foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
                        $v[$k1]['font_file'] = $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/Meiryo/Meiryo.ttf');
                        $lines[$k][$k1] = $v[$k1];
                    }
                }

                $draw[$key]['lines'] = $lines;
            }

        }
        // Update the $draw array to add your font
        return [$page, $draw, $pageSettings];
    }
}
```

We need to get the font from: `$this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/Meiryo/Meiryo.ttf')`.
However, this way is for drawing item, not for shipping address info. Because the shipping address part used the protected functions to set font style.

*vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php*

```
protected function _setFontRegular()

protected function _setFontBold()

protected function _setFontItalic()
```

Comment: thank you, this part worked and now half of the pdf font changed as expected.
I edited 
protected function _setFontRegular()

protected function _setFontBold()

protected function _setFontItalic()

in the core file and the changes were successful.
I have got 2 questions:

1) how do I override in the three setFont functions in the same module that I created?
2) the NIS symbol appeared but the words are still reversed, maybe it's a problem of encoding?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Which is the `the NIS symbol`? If we want to override the protected functions, we should override these classes, for example: we need to override `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`, `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php`.

Comment: this is how it looks after the AddFontToPdf.php change: 
https://s23.postimg.org/ngmkgcye3/image.png
 you can see that ass you said the symbol appeared on the shipping zone. 
my new module is as following:
[https://s23.postimg.org/d1c2wmbbv/pdf.jpg

What do I need to do in order to override the functions?
thanks again

Comment: I see. The currency shows correctly for order items. However, for example, for the shipping, may this uses the protected functions. We need to override them. As I said above,  for example: we need to override `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`, `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php`.

Comment: Yes ,I understand. but I'm asking **how** to override the AbstractPdf.php file.  can I contact you somehow to explain myself better?  thanks!

Comment: I tried to change _setFontRegular like this: 
`<?php 

namespace Ochos\fixPDF\Plugin; 

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList; 

class fixFontInAbstractPdf extends 
 Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf
 {
     protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/Alef/Alef-regular.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }
 }`

what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix these issues for my site.

**1.** Make a module the usual way.

*app/code/MyVendor/PdfFont/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment" type="MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment" />
</config>
```

*app/code/MyVendor/PdfFont/registration.php*

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MyVendor_PdfFont',
    __DIR__
);
```

**2.** Use di.xml to override the Shipment, Invoice and Creditmemo classes.

*app/code/MyVendor/PdfFont/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment" type="MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment" />

    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />

    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Creditmemo" type="MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf\Creditmemo" />
</config>
```

**3.** Add Shipment, Invoice and Creditmemo overrides.
These classes are just an exact copy of the classes from Magento but now they extend our custom class HebrewPdf instead of AbstractPdf.
**Note** I have only included the full Shipment class and truncated the Invoice and Creditmemo classes due to hitting stackoverflow character limit.

*MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment.php*

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf;

/**
 * Sales Order Shipment PDF model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Shipment extends \MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf\HebrewPdf
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface
     */
    protected $_localeResolver;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_localeResolver = $localeResolver;
        parent::__construct(
            $paymentData,
            $string,
            $scopeConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $pdfConfig,
            $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $inlineTranslation,
            $addressRenderer,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Draw table header for product items
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        /* Add table head */
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
        $this->y -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));

        //columns headers
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 100];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 35];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 10];

        $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->y -= 20;
    }

    /**
     * Return PDF document
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment[] $shipments
     * @return \Zend_Pdf
     */
    public function getPdf($shipments = [])
    {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('shipment');

        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);
        foreach ($shipments as $shipment) {
            if ($shipment->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->emulate($shipment->getStoreId());
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($shipment->getStoreId());
            }
            $page = $this->newPage();
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $shipment->getStore());
            /* Add address */
            $this->insertAddress($page, $shipment->getStore());
            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $shipment,
                $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                    self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_SHIPMENT_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $order->getStoreId()
                )
            );
            /* Add document text and number */
            $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Packing Slip # ') . $shipment->getIncrementId());
            /* Add table */
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
            /* Add body */
            foreach ($shipment->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
        }
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        if ($shipment->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->revert();
        }
        return $pdf;
    }

    /**
     * Create new page and assign to PDF object
     *
     * @param  array $settings
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Page
     */
    public function newPage(array $settings = [])
    {
        /* Add new table head */
        $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
        $this->y = 800;
        if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
        }
        return $page;
    }
}
```

*MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php*

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;

/**
 * Sales Order Invoice PDF model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Invoice extends \MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf\HebrewPdf
{
    // Code omitted due to hitting stack overflow character limit
    // Copy the rest of the code from Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
}
```

*MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf\Creditmemo.php*

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf;

/**
 * Sales Order Creditmemo PDF model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Creditmemo extends \MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf\HebrewPdf
{
    // Code omitted due to hitting stack overflow character limit
    // Copy the rest of the code from Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Creditmemo
}
```

**4.** Add HebrewPdf which extends `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf` and replaces `_setFontRegular()`, `_setFontBold()`, `_setFontItalic()` and `insertOrder()` methods.

Note the use of the Arimo font, I got that from Google fonts by searching for fonts that support Hebrew.

In the `insertOrder()` method I put in some code which passes text to the `utf8HebrewStrrev()` method which detects and reverses Hebrew text. In my example I am only reversing Hebrew in (Order date, billing address, shipping address, payment methods, shipping methods). You may need to add detects for other parts. I have labeled all edits in this method with:-

```
// ---------- START: PdfFont Edit
// some code ...
// ---------- END: PdfFont Edit
```

To make it easy to see what's been added. compare it with the `insertOrder()` found in `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf`

*MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf\HebrewPdf.php*

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\PdfFont\Model\Order\Pdf;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class HebrewPdf extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $paymentData,
            $string,
            $scopeConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $pdfConfig,
            $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $inlineTranslation,
            $addressRenderer,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check for Hebrew strings, if Hebrew is found the text is reversed.
     * This is because there is a bug with Zend PDF that reverses Hebrew words.
     * We are preemptively reversing them so when Zend Pdf reverses them it is actually correct the words back to normal.
     */
    public function utf8HebrewStrrev($str) {
        preg_match('/\p{Hebrew}/u', $str, $matches);

        if (count($matches) > 0) {
            preg_match_all('/./us', $str, $ar);
            $str = join('',array_reverse($ar[0]));
        }

        return $str;
    }

    /**
     * Override from: \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf
     *
     * Set font as regular
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    public function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/Arimo/Arimo-Regular.ttf')
        );

        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    /**
     * Override from: \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf
     *
     * Set font as bold
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    public function _setFontBold($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/Arimo/Arimo-Bold.ttf')
        );

        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    /**
     * Override from: \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf
     *
     * Set font as italic
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    public function _setFontItalic($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/Arimo/Arimo-Italic.ttf')
        );

        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    /**
     * Override from: \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf
     *
     * Insert order to pdf page
     *
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page &$page
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $obj
     * @param bool $putOrderId
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
    {
        if ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order) {
            $shipment = null;
            $order = $obj;
        } elseif ($obj instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment) {
            $shipment = $obj;
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        }

        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $top = $this->y;

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 55);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->setDocHeaderCoordinates([25, $top, 570, $top - 55]);
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);

        if ($putOrderId) {
            $page->drawText(__('Order # ') . $order->getRealOrderId(), 35, $top -= 30, 'UTF-8');
        }

        // ---------- START: PdfFont Edit
        // Check for Hebrew text in Order date
        $orderDate = $this->_localeDate->formatDate(
            $this->_localeDate->scopeDate(
                $order->getStore(),
                $order->getCreatedAt(),
                true
            ),
            \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
            false
        );
        $orderDateSplit = explode(' ', $orderDate);
        foreach ($orderDateSplit as $key => $value) {
            $orderDateSplit[$key] = $this->utf8HebrewStrrev($value);
        }
        $orderDate = implode(' ', $orderDateSplit);
        // ---------- END: PdfFont Edit

        $page->drawText(
            __('Order Date: ') .
            $orderDate,
            35,
            $top -= 15,
            'UTF-8'
        );

        $top -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 275, $top - 25);
        $page->drawRectangle(275, $top, 570, $top - 25);

        /* Calculate blocks info */

        /* Billing Address */
        $billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getBillingAddress(), 'pdf'));

        /* Payment */
        $paymentInfo = $this->_paymentData->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true)->toPdf();
        $paymentInfo = htmlspecialchars_decode($paymentInfo, ENT_QUOTES);
        $payment = explode('{{pdf_row_separator}}', $paymentInfo);
        foreach ($payment as $key => $value) {
            if (strip_tags(trim($value)) == '') {
                unset($payment[$key]);
            }
        }
        reset($payment);

        /* Shipping Address and Method */
        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            /* Shipping Address */
            $shippingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getShippingAddress(), 'pdf'));
            $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingDescription();
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
        $page->drawText(__('Sold to:'), 35, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $page->drawText(__('Ship to:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        } else {
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method:'), 285, $top - 15, 'UTF-8');
        }

        $addressesHeight = $this->_calcAddressHeight($billingAddress);
        if (isset($shippingAddress)) {
            $addressesHeight = max($addressesHeight, $this->_calcAddressHeight($shippingAddress));
        }

        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top - 25, 570, $top - 33 - $addressesHeight);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $this->y = $top - 40;
        $addressesStartY = $this->y;

        foreach ($billingAddress as $value) {
            if ($value !== '') {
                $text = [];
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    $text[] = $_value;
                }
                foreach ($text as $part) {
                    // ---------- START: PdfFont Edit
                    // Check for Hebrew text in billing address
                    $part = $this->utf8HebrewStrrev($part);
                    // ---------- END: PdfFont Edit
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        $addressesEndY = $this->y;

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $this->y = $addressesStartY;
            foreach ($shippingAddress as $value) {
                if ($value !== '') {
                    $text = [];
                    foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                        $text[] = $_value;
                    }
                    foreach ($text as $part) {
                        // ---------- START: PdfFont Edit
                        // check for Hebrew text in shipping address
                        $part = $this->utf8HebrewStrrev($part);
                        // ---------- END: PdfFont Edit
                        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                        $this->y -= 15;
                    }
                }
            }

            $addressesEndY = min($addressesEndY, $this->y);
            $this->y = $addressesEndY;

            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 275, $this->y - 25);
            $page->drawRectangle(275, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 25);

            $this->y -= 15;
            $this->_setFontBold($page, 12);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            $page->drawText(__('Payment Method'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $page->drawText(__('Shipping Method:'), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');

            $this->y -= 10;
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));

            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

            $paymentLeft = 35;
            $yPayments = $this->y - 15;
        } else {
            $yPayments = $addressesStartY;
            $paymentLeft = 285;
        }

        foreach ($payment as $value) {
            if (trim($value) != '') {
                //Printing "Payment Method" lines
                $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $value);
                foreach ($this->string->split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                    // ---------- START: PdfFont Edit
                    // Check for Hebrew text in payment method
                    $_value = $this->utf8HebrewStrrev($_value);
                    // ---------- END: PdfFont Edit
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), $paymentLeft, $yPayments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yPayments -= 15;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $yPayments = min($addressesEndY, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $top - 25, 25, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(570, $top - 25, 570, $yPayments);
            $page->drawLine(25, $yPayments, 570, $yPayments);

            $this->y = $yPayments - 15;
        } else {
            $topMargin = 15;
            $methodStartY = $this->y;
            $this->y -= 15;

            foreach ($this->string->split($shippingMethod, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                // ---------- START: PdfFont Edit
                // check for Hebrew text in Shipping methods
                $_value = $this->utf8HebrewStrrev($_value);
                // ---------- END: PdfFont Edit
                $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), 285, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                $this->y -= 15;
            }

            $yShipments = $this->y;
            $totalShippingChargesText = "(" . __(
                    'Total Shipping Charges'
                ) . " " . $order->formatPriceTxt(
                    $order->getShippingAmount()
                ) . ")";

            $page->drawText($totalShippingChargesText, 285, $yShipments - $topMargin, 'UTF-8');
            $yShipments -= $topMargin + 10;

            $tracks = [];
            if ($shipment) {
                $tracks = $shipment->getAllTracks();
            }
            if (count($tracks)) {
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
                $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
                $page->drawRectangle(285, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);
                $page->drawLine(400, $yShipments, 400, $yShipments - 10);
                //$page->drawLine(510, $yShipments, 510, $yShipments - 10);

                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 9);
                $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
                //$page->drawText(__('Carrier'), 290, $yShipments - 7 , 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Title'), 290, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText(__('Number'), 410, $yShipments - 7, 'UTF-8');

                $yShipments -= 20;
                $this->_setFontRegular($page, 8);
                foreach ($tracks as $track) {
                    $maxTitleLen = 45;
                    $endOfTitle = strlen($track->getTitle()) > $maxTitleLen ? '...' : '';
                    $truncatedTitle = substr($track->getTitle(), 0, $maxTitleLen) . $endOfTitle;
                    $page->drawText($truncatedTitle, 292, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $page->drawText($track->getNumber(), 410, $yShipments, 'UTF-8');
                    $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
                }
            } else {
                $yShipments -= $topMargin - 5;
            }

            $currentY = min($yPayments, $yShipments);

            // replacement of Shipments-Payments rectangle block
            $page->drawLine(25, $methodStartY, 25, $currentY);
            //left
            $page->drawLine(25, $currentY, 570, $currentY);
            //bottom
            $page->drawLine(570, $currentY, 570, $methodStartY);
            //right

            $this->y = $currentY;
            $this->y -= 15;
        }
    }

    // needed just because this inherits from abstract class
    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks again for sharing the solution. But I receive an error while trying to compile:   [ReflectionException]                                     
  Class Ochos\fixPDF\Model\Order\Pdf\Config does not exist  - Did you create any Config file?

Comment: for remove (total shipping charge 0.00) i have overridden abstractPdf.php file but not working. Is it working for you ?