# Magento 2 pdf generation not in proper language

Tags: sales-order, invoice, pdf, magento-2.1.7

In my Magento 2 site having three language stores English,Chinese,Chinese Traditional.All working fine But when comming to PDF in chinise orders it was printing boxes what can i do for fixing this problem

[image]

Please any help .I fallowed belowed links

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9666

[Hebrew words in PDF invoice are reversed and currency symbol not showing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150820/hebrew-words-in-pdf-invoice-are-reversed-and-currency-symbol-not-showing)

https://www.sonassi.com/blog/knowledge-base/magento-wrong-charset-conversion-from-utf-16be-to-utf-8-is-not-allowed

Answer (score 1):

The way I managed to fix it is that I rewrite the

> AbstractPdf.php

file

and within that I used a different font file which was compatible with foreign characters.

I updated these functions:-

```
protected function _setFontRegular()

protected function _setFontBold()

protected function _setFontItalic()
```

Comment: Hello @law Which font library have you used for Chinese character?

Comment: I think I used LinLibertineFont and placed it in lib/internal the entire folder, I also needed to changed the functions wrote above to pick the library

Comment: LinLibertineFont, it's default library it is not supported Chinese character.

Comment: I am sorry, I really do not remember, you see it was posted last year. But I am quite confident I found on internet the same font with chinese compatible version.

Comment: Yes you are right magento2 uses default that font, I am really sorry I do not have the link with me right now.

Comment: its ok. I have already tried 5 to 10 font library but no success.